# How do you suggest in a poem that the narrator has dementia or a mental illness?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

How do you suggest in a poem that the narrator has dementia or a mental illness? I am thinking of using metaphors such as broken mirror and distorted reflections, but more specifically is there anything else you can use? I was trying to think of an allegory, but I can't think of a specific allegory related to mental illness? Do you know any? How do you research allegories?

Comment: A great analogy for dementia that one of my friends had was that it's a black hole, or an object that consumes. It chews up the brain and devours memories, and eats who that person used to be. There's all kinds of allegories you can use; think bigger than the cliche of broken mirrors!

Comment: Fog or darkness swallowing up memories or representations of memories (like people or significant objects or places) might also work. Or waves washing away foot prints or images drawn in the sand. A cliff crumbling. Leaves being blown off a tree. A net tearing, spilling its contents.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to reveal the character with dementia as like a twist at the end, or do you want it to be in the beginning? Broken mirrors can have multiple meanings, so make sure to be direct, like including the words lost, forgetting, etc.

Comment: I think it also depends on whether OP *wants* to be direct; their use of the term "suggest" implies they don't want to say it outright.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think about it, forgetting means memories disappearing. So any metaphor involving things being lost or fading would work. Wind and water can both serve as metaphors for time. Dementia also means a loss of identity, so yes, broken mirrors fit.

Ideas:

- Fog or darkness swallowing up representations of memories (like people or significant objects or places)
- A fogged up mirror
- A hall of mirrors, tricking the viewer at every corner
- Waves washing away foot prints or images drawn in the sand
- A fading photograph
- A map or drawing soaked in liquid, slowly dissolving
- Leaves being blown off a tree
- Some kind of container with a hole, leaking its contents
- A boat in a storm being torn lose from its anchoring and carried away
- The ground crumbling under the narrator's feat, for example, near the edge of a cliff